# Azure web role with two sites, cannot bind to two different endpoints

Tags: binding, azure, web, role, endpoints

Inside a single azure web role, I have two endpoints. I have two sites, each one binding to different endpoints. Like this:

```
<WebRole name="MyWebRole">
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name ="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80"/>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="Certificate1" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name ="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn"/>

        </Bindings>

      </Site>
      <Site name="Open" physicalDirectory="..\..\NotSecure">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name ="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn"/>
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
```

When running this in the debugger, I get an error saying

> "There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL "http://127.255.0.0:82" for role instance ....

ok, so looking in IIS manager, I find the deployment. Click: http://127.255.0.0:82/ on browse. It comes up fine. Browse to the other one. The site comes up, too.

However, acknowledging the error stops the debugger and deletes the deployment.

Is this sort of configuration not allowed? Would rather avoid virtual directories. Just want two very different web sites to run based on http or https, on the same domain.  What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that is not mentioned in very many places.  If you have a site with a name of Web some of the information is overridden with default values, including some of the binding information.  Try changing the name of your first site to be something else like "Secure".